# How can I replace comma instead of some phrases?

Tags: c#

I have a string of characters that starts with a space and has `\r\n`,I want to delete the first space and delete `\r\n` then replace it with a comma after the word if there is a space?

My String : `"\r\n                        ram\r\ncomputer\r\n" ....`

I want the following mode to change? `laptop,computer,ram`

Comment: Was the problem resolved? Did you able to made any progress on it?

Answer (score 1):

As per @valuator answer you can use Trim() to remove trailing spaces. And to address other concerns pointed out in comments, you can use regex replace as below.

```
string myString = " laptop  computer ram";
var rx= new Regex(@"[\s]+");
myString= rx.Replace(myString.Trim(), ",");
```

the regex  `[\s]+` will match any whitespace characters

Comment: `[\s]+` This gives an error

Comment: I hope you are getting unrecognized sequence error. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Trim()` to remove the space at the beginning (and/or end) and then `Replace()` to replace the space between words with commas.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-6.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0

```
string myString = " laptop computer ram";
string newString = myString.Trim().Replace(' ', ',');
```

Comment: I know it's not in the question, but just a note that this won't work if there are multiple spaces between words. You'll end up with `laptop,,computer,,ram` if there are two spaces between each, for example.

Comment: `"\r\n                        ram\r\ncomputer\r\n"`   What if this is the case?